# Custom winid definition with EVT_MENU

Tags: event-handling, wxwidgets

I am a beginner in wxWidgets and so this is a very basic thing I'm having trouble with. I want to know how to define a custom winid like "ID_MENU_CIRCLE" with EVT_MENU which already has defined winid's.

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(ShapeFrame,wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_MENU_CIRCLE, ShapeFrame::OnModelCircle)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably mixing up event *IDs* and event *types*. All menu items generate events of `wxEVT_MENU` type, but each event carries its own unique ID, corresponding to the ID of the menu item that generated it. And menu item IDs are just unique integers allowing you to uniquely identify the items.

So your `ID_MENU_CIRCLE` can be just any integer and could be just

```
const int ID_MENU_CIRCLE = 100;
```

but it's common to use an enum to define these constants because you'd typically have many of them:

```
enum {
     ID_MENU_CIRCLE = 100,
     ID_MENU_SQUARE,
     ...
};
```